# java error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I want to convert JTextfield to int but java.lang.NullPointerException
get numText through JTextfield.
first convert to String and second, convert String into Integer and put that into other class.

```
package fitness_2;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import fitness_2.Person.Calculation;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class fitness extends JFrame {
    Calculation cal = null;
    public fitness()  {
        try {
         
        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        
        }catch(Exception e) {
        
        }
    
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel numOfPerson = new JLabel("number of members:");
        JTextField numText = new JTextField(4);
        JButton submitBtn = new JButton ("SUBMIT");
    
        panel.add(numOfPerson);
        panel.add(numText);
        panel.add(submitBtn);
        String n = numText.getText();
        submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
    
        submitBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                cal = new Calculation();
                if(!checkStr(n)) {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(n);
                    cal.CalculationPane(num);    

                }
                
            }});
  
    
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
        boolean checkStr(String s){
        boolean result = false;
        for(int i = 0 ;i < s.length();i++) {
            if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                result = false;
            }else
                result = true;
            }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new fitness();
    }
}
```

then, error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at fitness_2.Person$Calculation.CalculationPane(Calculation.java:73)
at fitness_2.fitness$2.mouseClicked(fitness.java:44)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6639)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

and Calculation code

```
package fitness_2;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import fitness_2.Person.Calculation;

import java.awt.event.*;

class Person {
    String name;
    int waitingTime;
    int satisfaction;
    int dissatisfaction;
    int index;

    Person () {
    }

    Person (String name, int waitingTime, int satisfaction, int 
dissatisfaction, int index) {
        this.name = name;
        this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
        this.satisfaction = satisfaction;
        this.dissatisfaction = dissatisfaction;
        this.index = index;
    }

static class Calculation implements MouseListener{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;
    JPanel panel3;
    JTextField nameText, timeText, satisfactionText, dissatisfactionText;
    JButton calBtn;

    void CalculationPane(int n) {
        frame = new JFrame("Scheduling");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        panel3 = new JPanel();
    
        Person p[] = new Person[n];
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
            JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Enter name: ", JLabel.CENTER);
            JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel("Enter waiting time: ",JLabel.CENTER);
            JLabel satisLabel = new JLabel("Enter satisfaction: ",JLabel.CENTER);
            JLabel dissatisLabel = new JLabel("Enter dissatisfaction: ",JLabel.CENTER);
        
            panel1.add(nameLabel);
            panel1.add(timeLabel);
            panel1.add(satisLabel);
            panel1.add(dissatisLabel);
        
            nameText = new JTextField(20);
            nameText.addMouseListener(this);
            timeText = new JTextField(3);
            timeText.addMouseListener(this);
            satisfactionText = new JTextField(4);
            satisfactionText.addMouseListener(this);
            dissatisfactionText = new JTextField(4);
            dissatisfactionText.addMouseListener(this);
        
            panel2.add(nameText);
            panel2.add(timeText);
            panel2.add(satisfactionText);
            panel2.add(dissatisfactionText);
        
        
            p[i].name = nameText.getText();
            p[i].waitingTime =Integer.parseInt(timeText.getText().trim());
            p[i].satisfaction = Integer.parseInt(satisfactionText.getText().trim());
            p[i].dissatisfaction = Integer.parseInt(dissatisfactionText.getText().trim());
            p[i].index = i;
        
        }
        calBtn = new JButton("Scheduling");
        calBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
    
        calBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                        if ((double)p[j].dissatisfaction / ((double)p[j].waitingTime + 1) < (double)p[j + 1].dissatisfaction / ((double)p[j + 1].waitingTime + 1)) {
                            Person temp = new Person();
                            temp = p[j + 1];
                            p[j + 1] = p[j];
                            p[j] = temp;
                        }
                        else if ((double)p[j].dissatisfaction / (double)p[j].waitingTime == (double)p[j + 1].dissatisfaction / (double)p[j + 1].waitingTime) {
                            if (p[j].dissatisfaction > p[j + 1].dissatisfaction * p[j + 1].waitingTime)
                                continue;
                            else
                            {
                                Person temp = new Person();
                                temp = p[j + 1];
                                p[j + 1] = p[j];
                                p[j] = temp;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            continue;
                    }
                }

                int tot_satisfaction = 0;
                System.out.println("Order of use: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.println(p[i].index);
                    if (i < p[i].waitingTime) {
                        tot_satisfaction += p[i].satisfaction;
                    }
                    else
                        tot_satisfaction += p[i].satisfaction - ((i - p[i].waitingTime) * p[i].dissatisfaction);
            }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total satisfaction: " + tot_satisfaction);

            }
       });  
    }  
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    }
}
}
```

how can I fix them? I apply exception. but nothing was changed.
Additionally, replacing "" to "0" either doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the getting of `numText` value inside button click, because the value will change each time and you need to get it everytime on click:

you defined the `Calculation` class inside Person class and its static, so to access the calculation, firstly you need to remove `static` from Calculation class or define the `CalculationPane` method as `static` to make it accessible from class, I removed the `static` keywork from `Calculation`

```
class Calculation {
}
```

and you need to initialize the Calculation class from Person class object ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)):

```
submitBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        cal = new Person();
        String n = numText.getText();
        if (!checkStr(n)) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(n);
            Person.Calculation c =  cal.new Calculation();
            c.CalculationPane(num);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That’s not work..

Comment: @dongdongre did you entered some value inside the `numText` ?

Comment: yes number format exception was fixed but new error that null pointer exception.

Comment: @dongdongre you need to update the code and the output error

Comment: kk. updated the code and error

Comment: @dongdongre the problem also related to `Calculation.java:73` your Calculation class, and you need also at it.

Comment: @dongdongre I updated the code, please check: